# calling services using launch files

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I call a service by using a launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46902/calling-services-using-launch-files/) by [Ratan Sadan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3482/ratan-sadan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-10-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For an example of calling a service via a minimal node as @sam says, check out the [kinect_breaker_enabler.py](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/fb8354a98ac5/turtlebot_node/scripts/kinect_breaker_enabler.py) node from the official TurtleBot stacks.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can write a node to call ROS service,and use roslaunch to run launch file which will run that node.

---

Originally posted by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) with karma: 2570 on 2012-10-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3